# Quantifier free L-rings sentence

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

So my question is as follows:
Let $\phi$ be the $L_{\text{rings}}$-sentence
$$\exists x(x^2+1=0\ \wedge x+1\neq0)$$
Give a quantifier-free $L_{\text{rings}}$-sentence $\psi$ which is $T_{\text{acf}}$ equivalent to  $\phi$, where $T_{\text{acf}}$ the theory of algebraically closed fields.
I don't even know how to start

Answer (score 3):

Think semantically. When $\varphi,\psi$ are sentences and $T$ is a theory, $\varphi$ is $T$-equivalent to $\psi$ iff the models of $T$ satisfying $\varphi$ are exactly the models of $T$ satisfying $\psi$. So if you want to find a "nice" $\psi$ which is $T$-equivalent to a given $\varphi$, the first step is to understand:

> What are the models of $T$ which satisfy $\varphi$?

(More snappily, what are the models of $T\cup\{\varphi\}$?)

So in this particular case, what are the algebraically closed fields (= models of $T_{acl}$) where $-1$ has a square root other than $-1$ (= where $\exists x(x^2+1=0\wedge x+1\not=0)$)? Keep in mind that since we're looking at algebraically closed fields, we **are** guaranteed to have at least one square root of $-1$.

> Suppose $F$ is an algebraically closed field. Since we know that $-1$ has a square root, as long as $(-1)^2\not=-1$ we know $F$ satisfies the sentence in question. Conversely, it's not hard to show that if $(-1)^2=-1$ then $-1$ is in fact the *only* square root of $-1$ in $F$. So what fields satisfy $(-1)^2\not=-1$? Can you see a way to write down a quantifier-free first-order sentence which characterizes these?

Comment: Ok sorry for the delayed reaction. But the only field I can thank of is the complex field. Is that right?

Comment: @Whateverittakes $\mathbb{C}$ is definitely one algebraically closed field, but there are others. (Think about the **characteristic** of a field ...)

Comment: Well the characteristic of $\mathbb{C}$ is 0 right?

Comment: @Whateverittakes Yes. But there are algebraically closed fields whose characteristic *isn't* $0$. Now, do you see a connection between field characteristic and your sentence $\varphi$?

Comment: Ah yes so in the ring there exists an a such that $a+1=0$ (namely $x^2=a$). So I am indeed in search for a non zero characteristic. But I'm sorry I can not see what field I'm looking for :(. Model theory is not my strong side